# opengl crashing when use glew

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

opengl crash when use glew when i use these 3 lines under unsigned int buffer

```
    if (glfwInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
}

float positions[6] = {
     -0.5, -0.5,
     0, 0.5,
     0.5, -0.5
};
unsigned int buffer;


//glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6* sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

it show me Error in console but don't crash expect when i use the three codes 
under unsigned int buffer i watched the cherno project and tried his code but it's the same error i think because my gpu is old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Ripi2's answer:

> That's for glfw (window gui) not glew (function pointers to OGL API)

this means that:

GLFW is used for creating OpenGL contexts, meaning creating windows. It has code for window creation on various platforms so you don't have to write the code yourself.

GLEW just gets your OpenGL implementation for you to use via function pointers.

Therefore, you should always `#include <GL/glew.h>` before `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h`.

You can check for GLFW init by:

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
...
}
```

You can check GLEW init by:

```
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
...
}
```

Comment: i included glew before glfw3 but i still want to know why it chash when i tried if(!glfwInit()) don't show me error

Comment: If you don't use `glew` the function pointer `glBindBuffer` points to somewhere not defined (instead to a point in the OGL driver) and you get a crash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize [*GLEW*](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Call [`glewInit`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) right after you created the OpenGL context:

```cpp
if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE ) {
    // error handling
    // ...
}

GLFWwindow *wnd = glfwCreateWindow( ... );
if ( wnd == nullptr ) {
    // error handling
    // ...
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK ) {
    // error handling
    // ...
}
```

Note, that [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) returns `GLEW_OK` if succeeded. [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) initializes the function pointers for the OpenGL functions.  If you try to call function via an uninitialized function pointer, a segmentation fault occurs.

Glew can enable additional extensions by `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. See the [GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) which says:

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

Answer (score -1):

`glfwInit()` ? No. That's for `glfw` (window gui) not `glew` (function pointers to OGL API) . Use `glewInit()`